# Terrain for Billboard effect in OpenGL 3.3 not working

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to run the "Cacti in the Desert" Billboard example from Chapter 15 of the OpenGL Game Programming book (Book source code [available here](http://glbook.gamedev.net/GLBOOK/glbook.gamedev.net/source.html)). I'm having difficulty getting the desert terrain to be visible on my screen. I'm using GLFW for my window and the example code created it's own window, could this be the issue?

Or, could the issue be with the DisplayScene() function below. In this function, do I have to somehow set the following matrices from my camera class?

```
ViewMatrix = camera[currentCamera]->GetViewMatrix();
ProjectionMatrix = camera[currentCamera]->GetViewProjectionMatrix();
```

Here's the DisplayScene() function from the Cacti demo:

```
BOOL DisplayScene()
{
  // used to track the orientation of the viewer
  static GLfloat s_eye[] = { MAP_X * MAP_SCALE * 0.5, 8.0, -MAP_Z * MAP_SCALE * 0.5};
  static GLfloat s_at[]  = { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 };
  static GLfloat s_angle = -90.0;
  float speed = 0.3f;

  // check for rotation
  if (g_keys[VK_LEFT])
  {
    s_angle -= 2.0;
  }
  if (g_keys[VK_RIGHT])
  {
    s_angle += 2.0;
  }

  // run if the shift key is pressed
  if (KEY_DOWN(VK_SHIFT))
    speed = speed * 2;

  float rad =  float(PI*s_angle/180.0f);

  // check for forward and backward motion
  if (g_keys[VK_UP])
  {
    s_eye[2] += (float)sin(rad) * speed;
    s_eye[0] += (float)cos(rad) * speed;
  }
  if (g_keys[VK_DOWN])
  {
    s_eye[2] -= (float)sin(rad) * speed;
    s_eye[0] -= (float)cos(rad) * speed;
  }

  // do bound's checking to make sure they don't leave the map
  if (s_eye[0] < MAP_SCALE)
    s_eye[0] = MAP_SCALE;
  if (s_eye[0] > (MAP_X - 2) * MAP_SCALE)
    s_eye[0] = (MAP_X - 2) * MAP_SCALE;
  if (s_eye[2] < -(MAP_Z - 2) * MAP_SCALE)
    s_eye[2] = -(MAP_Z - 2) * MAP_SCALE;
  if (s_eye[2] > - MAP_SCALE)
    s_eye[2] = -MAP_SCALE;

  // set the eye position in relation to the ground
  s_eye[1] = GetHeight(s_eye[0], s_eye[2]) + 2.0f;

  //set the look at point to be at eye level in the direction the viewer is headed
  s_at[0] = float(s_eye[0] + 100*cos(rad));
  s_at[2] = float(s_eye[2] + 100*sin(rad));
  s_at[1] = s_eye[1];

  // set up the modelview matrix according to this viewer orientation
  glLoadIdentity();
  gluLookAt(s_eye[0], s_eye[1], s_eye[2],
    s_at[0], s_at[1], s_at[2],
    0.0, 1.0, 0.0
    );

  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

  DrawSand();
  DrawCacti();

  return TRUE;
} // end DisplayScene()
```

Here is the DrawSand() function to draw the terrain:

```
void DrawSand()
{
  // select the sand texture
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, g_sand);
  glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);

  // loop through all the triangle strips
  for (int z = 0; z < MAP_Z-1; z++)
  {
    // draw the triangles in this strip
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, MAP_X * 2, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, &g_indexArray[z * MAP_X * 2]);
  }


} // end DrawSand()
```

Comment: Probably not the issue, but it seem weird that you use GL_MODULATE. This is deprecated functionality.

Comment: Yes, the Cacti example is a few years old. Would you happen to know of a more modern OpenGL billboard example that uses 2D images to simulate 3D objects?